Reduce 220 volts to 115 volts
I have a pool pump I replace that was 220 and the new one 115. It is hard wired and the circuit breaker is 2 20amp connected. What’s the best way to reduce the 220 to 115 ?

Step zero - standard supply voltages in North America have been 240/120 for decades. Pictures would be helpful to see what you have for wiring and breakers. [Edit] to add those to your question.

The 115 will need a neutral wire.  A neutral must be white, but white does not mean neutral.  Easy if you have the 220(240) wired up as black and white hot with ground, or black and red hot, a white neutral, and ground.  Just move white hot to neutral bus, or remove the red from the breaker.

Since you're halving the voltage, the current will double if the load is the same so check your wire sizes and breaker.

Have you removed the wiring cover on the pump? Are you sure that the pump can't be re-wired for 240 VAC? Pump motors often have 2 windings, wire in parallel for 120 VAC, series for 240 VAC. They will often have a simple diagram inside the cover explaining how to do this.

We are assuming this is in North America and both pumps are made for North American system.  If this is not so, add/edit into your question.  220v is common in Europe/very old American.  115/120 is North American, odd in Europe.

220 to 110V step down transformers are available. But I am not sure those will be helpful for your pump since it is rated to 115V.

If the breaker is dedicated to the pump, (does not feed anything else) and the amperage of the breaker and wires is adequate, and the wiring is a cable with black and white wires: you simply remove the white wire from the breaker, removing any marking (typically black or red tape on the white insulation) that it's a hot white (should be present, often not, though) and connect it to neutral.
If the wiring is in conduit and does not have a white or gray wire, you add one, connected to neutral.
If the cable is a 3-wire (black, white, red) with black & red connected to the breaker, make sure the white is connected to the neutral, and connect the motor to black and white or red and white.
A rare but annoying case would be if a sub-panel feeding this does not have a neutral at all, in which case you'll need to go all the way back to the main panel to run new cable, or wire in conduit, to supply a neutral.
